# I can't see the google maps in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-maps, maps

I cant see the google maps in my flutter app. I got api key.
[image]
[image]

I tried a lot of things, changing sdk version 21 and AndroidManifest.xml
I can see phone's google maps app and using android 12.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please set jdk path for  flutter sdk. 
Did you added SHA1 fingerprint to the console for generate google-services.json file ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to increase your chances of getting help from the community.